# char array of boolean numbers to 64 bit integer number

Tags: c++

I have an character array (say char charr[5]) which contains 0/1 (char array of boolean number). Now, I want to convert the character array to 64 bit integer number (if array is {0, 0, 0, 1 , 0}, it will give 2 ). How to do that ? Is there any library functions ?

Comment: Just do it by hand...it's not a particularly difficult problem to solve using bitwise operators.

Comment: If it is indeed a small array and you need this often I would build a look up table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no standard function for that. But it's pretty trivial:

```
uint64_t pack(const uint8_t *bits, size_t n)
{
  uint64_t x = 0, value = 1 << (n - 1);

  while(n > 0)
  {
    x += value * *bits++;
    n--;
    value /= 2;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: I'd get rid of `value` and just use shifts, but otherwise it's nice.

Answer (score 1):

Unwind has the basic idea right, but a complex implementation. This also works:

```
uint64_t pack(const uint8_t *bits, size_t n)
{
  uint64 x = 0;
  for(;n > 0; n--) // For all input bits.
  {
    x <<= 1; // make room for next bit.
    assert(*bits <= 1); // It better be a 0 or 1.
    x += *bits++; // Add new bit on the end.
  }
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [strtoll](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoll/) with base 2:

```
int val = strtoll(input, NULL, 2);
```

Comment: Uh no, that will expect `'0'` and `'1'`, i.e. digits, which is not what the input has.

Comment: @unwind: But that's fixable. Just add `'0'` to all digits. (Works if you have a `char[]`, not if you have a `const char*`, in which case you'd need to make a copy first)